# Why does VSCode debugger ignore raised exception despite the checkmark?

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I was debugging Pandas in VSCode (Python). I ran the following code in the debugger:

```py
import pandas as pd
index = pd.Index([1,2,3,4]).get_loc('w')
```

which resulted in an error (`KeyError: 'w'`). However, this error was not caught by the debugger, but simply printed in the output.

I expected the debugger to stop on the `raise` inside `except` here in this Pandas file ([permalink](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/bdb509f95a8c0ff16530cedb01c2efc822c0d314/pandas/core/indexes/base.py#L3652-L3655)):

```py
        try:
            return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
        except KeyError as err:
            raise KeyError(key) from err
```

I have the following breakpoint settings:

- (unchecked) Raised Exceptions
- (checked) Uncaught Exceptions
- (checked) User Uncaught Exceptions

and also `"justMyCode": false,` in my debugging profile in `launch.json`.

**Question**: How do I make VSCode debugger stop on this uncaught exception (instead of terminating and printing an error message)?

If I check "Raised Exceptions", then the debugger will stop <s>where I expect it to stop</s> inside `try`. But it will also stop tens of times in many other places, which I am not interested in, so this is not an option.

Now, if I follow the same code pattern and try this:

```py
try:
    print(1 / 0)
except ZeroDivisionError as err:
    raise ZeroDivisionError('bla') from err
```

then VSCode Python debugger will stop at the last line (and let me debug). This shows that raising inside `except` counts as an uncaught exception.

---

P.S. To answer @starball's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77724269/why-does-vscode-debugger-ignore-raised-exception-despite-the-checkmark?noredirect=1#comment137024764_77724269), if I run

```py
try:
    index = pd.Index([1,2,3,4]).get_loc('w')
except KeyError as err:
    raise KeyError('w') from err
```

exactly the same happens, as if I ran the same line without try-except.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63247025/11107541

Comment: out of curiosity, what happens if you wrap your `pd.Index([1,2,3,4]).get_loc('w')` with try and re-raise? does the debugger break at the re-raise then?

Comment: @starball Re your 2nd comment, please see the body. Re your 1st comment, thanks, good to learn about `GetGlobalDebugger()`'s flags. I double checked that `skip_on_exceptions_thrown_in_same_context == False`, as should be by default. Other than that, the answer given there is not applicable to my case. And the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63247025/while-debugging-how-can-i-break-on-raised-exceptions-except-for-specific-errors#comment111844446_63247025) by rioV8 therein aligns with my expectation that VSCode should stop at exceptions "that will bubble to the top of the stack".

Comment: for some reason this calls to mind https://stackoverflow.com/q/77353715/11107541, even though that's for NodeJS. most probably totally unrelated though.